# Dynamically importing libraries with importlib on setuptools entrypoint

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging, python-importlib

## What I am trying to achieve

My goal is, after installing the python package, to be able to run a command from a script that was not installed together.

### Example

```
$ excommand
Hello!
```

### Directory Structure

```
.
├── A
    ├── __init__.py
    └── cli.py
├── .venv
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── extra.py
└── extra_test.py
```

cli.py

```py
import importlib

def main():
    getattr(importlib.import_module('extra'), 'hello')()
```

extra.py

```py
def hello():
    print("Hello!")
```

extra_test.py

```py
import importlib

getattr(importlib.import_module('extra'), 'hello')()
```

pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = [ "setuptools" ]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = A
version = 1.0.0

[options]
packages = find:

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    hello = A.cli:main
```

## The Problem

After installing the package:

```
$ pip install .
```

The command `hello` does not work because `importlib` raises an Error:

```
$ hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extra'
```

## What was tried

I have assured that has something to do with the installation or importlib, because if I run `python3 extra_test.py` it runs normally and it does exactly the same as the command `hello` is suposed to do.

Comment: What I would do if I were in this situation is that right before the line with `importlib.import_module('extra')` I would write `import sys; print(sys.path)` in order to check if the directory listed is the one containing `extra.py` as a debug help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.

Refer to @sinoroc's debugging suggestions. It is found that if you start the script from `entry_points`, `sys.path` does not have `os.getcwd()`.

finally:

```py
# cli.py
sys.path.append("./")
```